# Google Sheets API row.getCustomElements().getTags() doesnt return any values

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to Android world. I have been referring lot of tutorials to finally create an app accessing data from Google sheets. I have gone through lot of threads but everyone is suggesting same format as I have used in my codes below but it is not returning any values.

My code is..

private void getData()throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException,
            IOException, ServiceException, URISyntaxException{

```
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

    URL SPREADSHEET_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/14-oj9z-Z6_sGtrOdL9nqvV604yZxAUw33bAJY8tcYyw/public/basic");

    WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_URL,WorksheetFeed.class);
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = feed.getEntries();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);
    Log.d("hello","Worksheet Title is "+worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    Log.d("hello","Worksheet Row Count is "+Integer.toString(worksheet.getRowCount()));
    Log.d("hello","Worksheet Column Count is "+Integer.toString(worksheet.getColCount()));

    //URL listFeedURL = new URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString()).toURL();
    URL listFeedURL = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
    Log.d("hello","URL is \n"+ listFeedURL.toString());

    ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedURL,ListFeed.class);

    for (ListEntry row: listFeed.getEntries()){
        Log.d("hello","Title "+row.getTitle().getPlainText());
        Log.d("hello","Size "+Integer.toString(row.getCustomElements().getTags().size()));
        for (String tag: row.getCustomElements().getTags()){
            //Log.d("hello",ProperValue(row.getCustomElements().getValue(tag)));
            Log.d("hello d",row.getCustomElements().getValue(tag).toString());
        }
    }
```

and my log shows:

D/hello: Worksheet Title is contacts
D/hello: Worksheet Row Count is 1000
D/hello: Worksheet Column Count is 26
D/hello: URL is 
         https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/14-oj9z-Z6_sGtrOdL9nqvV604yZxAUw33bAJY8tcYyw/od6/public/basic
D/hello: Title 100
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 101
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 190
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 192
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 145
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 103
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 923
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 34
D/hello: Size 0
D/hello: Title 23
D/hello: Size 0

I am not sure what is missing though the listfeed url is fetched is absolutely correct as well.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to post such an immature question. I figured out the issue.
It was because I was using "/basic" in the end of URL. It should have been "/full"